# Why do a Beam io need beam.AddFixedKey+beam.GroupByKey to work properly?

Tags: go, elasticsearch, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm working on a Beam IO for Elasticsearch in Golang and at the moment I have a working draft version but, only managed to make it work by doing something that's not clear to me why do I need it.
Basically I looked at existing IO's and found that writes only work if I add the following:

```
x := beam.AddFixedKey(s, pColl)
y := beam.GroupByKey(s, x)
```

A full example is in the [existing BigQuery IO](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/5a029fd97d663e19a9bcd6bff61648bccbd7f95b/sdks/go/pkg/beam/io/bigqueryio/bigquery.go#L206)

Basically I would like to understand why do I need both AddFixedKey followed by a GroupByKey to make it work. Also checked the issue BEAM-3860, but doesn't have much more details about it.

Answer (score 1):

Those two transforms essentially function as a way to group all elements in a PCollection into one list. For example, its usage in the BigQuery example you posted allows grouping the entire input PCollection into a list that gets iterated over in the [ProcessElement method](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/5a029fd97d663e19a9bcd6bff61648bccbd7f95b/sdks/go/pkg/beam/io/bigqueryio/bigquery.go#L277).

Whether to use this approach depends how you are implementing the IO. The BigQuery example you posted performs its writes as a batch once all elements are available, but that may not be the best approach for your use case. You might prefer to write elements one at a time as they come in, especially if you can parallelize writes among different workers. In that case you would want to avoid grouping the input PCollection together.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Oliveira, that makes sense, thanks!